System.TypeLoadException : Could not load type 'OpenQA.Selenium.Internal.IWrapsElement' in selenium 4.19.0
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using YourNamespace.Page; // Import the appropriate WebDriver package for your browser

namespace YourNamespace
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class BrowserVersionTest
    {
        private IWebDriver driver; // Static driver instance

        [OneTimeSetUp]
        public void Setup()
        {
            // Initialize the WebDriver instance
            driver = new ChromeDriver(); // Use the appropriate WebDriver class for your browser
        }

        [Test]
        public void CheckBrowserVersion()
        {
            // Navigate to a website
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://facebook.com");
            Thread.Sleep(3000);
            var loginPage = new LoginFbPage(driver);
            loginPage.NavigateToResultPage();
        }

        [OneTimeTearDown]
        public void Teardown()
        {
            if (driver != null)
            {
                driver.Quit();
                driver.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
}

this is my code and I have some problem as you know the selenium.pageobject not support in selenium.support package instead of I am using the selenium.comminity and i can't not using pagefactory object can you help me please ?
How to learn document about POM in selenium version 4.19.0

Please [edit] your question to include a [repro]. We need to see the exception message and stacktrace, plus all relevant code to identify the source of the problem. Please also include which NuGet packages you are using (and the version numbers for those NuGet packages).
